# CSS Animation Delay Not Working With 2 Simaltanious Animations

Tags: css, css-animations

Im trying to run 2 CSS animations on some text.

The first animation makes the text fade from black to green...
But then I want the text after a certain amount of time to turn to a darker green
So basically have an 'Active' state and then a 'Inactive' state

I have got the timing and animation working properly for the first animation...
But for some reason the second animation isn't delaying the time its been asked to...
The second animation is just running as soon as the first animation is complete

```
<div class="topicLiRung" style='animation-name: active; animation-duration: 3s; animation-delay: ${weekData.delay}s; animation-fill-mode:forwards; animation-name: inactive;  animation-duration: 3s; animation-delay: ${weekData.inactive}s; animation-fill-mode:forwards;  '>${weekData.topic}</div>
```

This is the code im running, so its basically a div that has 2 amimations assinged to the style that has dynamic timing from server data.

Why isnt the seccond animation waiting the time its been asked?

Comment: That is not how animations get strung together. You have completely overwritten the setting of the first animation with the second one.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations for info on how to have multiple animations.

Comment: Thank you. Have just seen what I was doing wrong. Will try and implement it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of A Haworth's Comment...

Multiple CSS animations should be handled like this:

```
animation-name: fadeInOut, moveLeft300px, bounce;
animation-duration: 2.5s, 5s, 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 2, 1, 5;
```

Not the way I wrote it..

Hope this helps someone